# C# Threading and multi-user program

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I have a program that works as a back end for a serial terminal. This id intended to be a Fallout prop. I have this working fine with one serial port and one main program.

I would however like to make this is a functional, multi-user environment that opens on a selection on serial ports and has each one running in a seperate thread.

I'm not asking for a Blue Peter mirracle and "heres one I made earlier". I just some help understanding how Treading works properly.

So far I have had one simple threaded application that moved the cursor on the terminal, wrote the current time and the moved the cursor back once every minute.

The code for that is here:

```
static void StartClock()
{
TimerCallback tmCallback = WriteTime;
Timer timer = new Timer(tmCallback, null, 60000, 60000);
}

static void WriteTime(object WT)
{
string TimeDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
char[] TimeDateArr = TimeDate.ToCharArray();
string test = "";
Array.Reverse(TimeDateArr);
Array.Resize(ref TimeDateArr, 8);
Array.Reverse(TimeDateArr);
Array.Resize(ref TimeDateArr, 5);
foreach (char c in TimeDateArr)
{
test = test + c.ToString();
}
PositionCursor(75, 1);
write(test);
PositionCursor(2, 23);
}
```

My issue is not fully understanding how treading works.

If anyone could properly explain what parts of this are doing and maybe how I would look at starting what I want to do.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference between system.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer.
I think you need something like this;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer
        {
            AutoReset = true,
            Interval = 100,
            Enabled = true
        };
        timer.Elapsed += TimerOnElapsed;
        timer.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("do stuff on a interval");
    }
```

Comment: The OP asked a specific question. You haven't answered that. Answer the question first, then elaborate if you think there's a better way to do what they are doing.